# How to store data from method into an array angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my component I've got a method that retrieves data from my API like below:

```
export class OrderExceptionReportComponent implements OnInit {

  public sessionData: ExceptionReportSessionData[] = [];

  constructor(private orderExceptionReportService: OrderExceptionReportService) {
  }

  public async getExceptionReportSessionData(): Promise<void> {
    this.orderExceptionReportService.GetExceptionReportSessionData()
      .then(
        data => {
          this.sessionData = data;              
        });

  }
ngOnInit() {
    this.getExceptionReportSessionData();
    console.log(this.sessionData);
  }
```

I'm trying to store the data retrieved into `sessionData` array so I can use the data for a couple of filters I want to implement. When call `console.log(this.sessionData);` the array shows as undefined in the console.

How can I store the data from `getExceptionReportSessionData()` into an array so I have access to the data in other parts of my component?

Comment: What does orderExceptionReportService.GetExceptionReportSessionData return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem as though there are two mistakes in the above code. You aren't returning the promise from the method and you aren't awaiting the response of that promise.

Assuming there aren't other complications in your implementation of the `OrderExceptionReportService`, the following should solve your problem.

```
    export class OrderExceptionReportComponent implements OnInit {

      public sessionData: ExceptionReportSessionData[] = [];

      constructor(private orderExceptionReportService: OrderExceptionReportService) {
      }

      public getExceptionReportSessionData(): Promise<void> {
        return this.orderExceptionReportService.GetExceptionReportSessionData()
          .then(
            data => {
              this.sessionData = data;              
            });

      }
    ngOnInit() {
        await this.getExceptionReportSessionData();
        console.log(this.sessionData);
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are doing http async call data will be available only after async call is finished. Here you are trying to do log array immediate after call to API that will be undefined only.

You can access value of this array after assigning which you doing after promise resolved.

You have to call other filter related execution after your data assigned.